# config_file works wrong for sqlite3 database

Tags: cmake

Here is what am I doing:

```
#configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/xdb.db3 ${complex_BINARY_DIR}/) <-- works wrong
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/armd.conf ${complex_BINARY_DIR}/)
```

both files moves there properly but when I'm trying to use moved xdb.db3 my program and sqlite editor says `"xdb.db3 is not sqlite database or encrypted"`

How must I move sqlite database and why I can't do it with configure_file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `COPYONLY` flag to [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file).

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/xdb.db3 ${complex_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
```